# Selecting records with underscore as second character in a column in MySQL using 'like'

Tags: mysql, select

I know for selecting the records with 'a' as the second letter in a column we write the following query:-

```
Select * from table where column1 like '_a%';
```

For selecting the records with 'a' as the third letter in a column we write:-

```
Select * from table where column1 like '__a%';
```

Now I want select the records where the `column1` contains '_'(underscore) as the second character.For example, I want to select the records with `column1` like A_John, B_John, A_Jai and so on. What is the escape character I can use in this case. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Can you tell me how many records are there in that table..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
 Select * from books where title like '\_\_a%';
```

for two underscore at first and

```
Select * from books where title like '\_a%';
```

for single underscore at first and

Comment: This isn't correct.  In the example provided 'I want to select the records with column1 like A_John, B_John, A_Jai' neither of these queries will match

Comment: @macros: You have to run query like this 'A\_%' or if you want to any letter at first position then '_\_%'

Answer (score 1):

The '\' character is used to escape:

```
Select * from table where column1 like '_\_a%';
```

Comment: This will not match the examples provided in the question -  A_John, B_John, A_Jai

Answer (score 0):

\ is the escape character in MySQL. Use:

`Select * from table where column1 like '_\_%';`